# SystemTap simple demo fails

Tags: monitoring, debugging

Started learning [SystemTap](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/) using RedHat's manual.
Here is the [example](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html-single/SystemTap_Beginners_Guide/#syscall-open) I'm trying to run.

While executing `stap open.stp` I got the error:

```
[root@ror6ax ~]# stap open.stp
semantic error: while resolving probe point: identifier 'syscall' at open.stp:1:7
        source: probe syscall.open
                      ^

semantic error: no match
Pass 2: analysis failed.  [man error::pass2]
```

`open.stp` is as follows:

```
probe syscall.open
{
  printf ("%s(%d) open\n", execname(), pid())
}
```

System is RHEL6.5, x86_64

Comment: Doesn't work for me either....

Answer (score 1):

stap can be run in verbose mode (`stap -v`) to help identifying the root cause. Usually the case is missing kernel-debuginfo package (`yum install kernel-debuginfo-$(uname -r)`) which is not distributed with the standard RHEL.