# SystemTap simple demo fails - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, monitoring, debugging

Started learning [SystemTap](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/) using RedHat's manual.
Here is the [example](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html-single/SystemTap_Beginners_Guide/#syscall-open) I'm trying to run.

While executing `stap open.stp` I got the error:

```
[root@ror6ax ~]# stap open.stp
semantic error: while resolving probe point: identifier 'syscall' at open.stp:1:7
        source: probe syscall.open
                      ^

semantic error: no match
Pass 2: analysis failed.  [man error::pass2]
```

`open.stp` is as follows:

```
probe syscall.open
{
  printf ("%s(%d) open\n", execname(), pid())
}
```

System is Ubuntu 14.04

My question is similar to [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/133956/systemtap-simple-demo-fails), but is for a different OS.

Answer (score 0):

I followed these instructions from [this page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Systemtap):

```
   codename=$(lsb_release -c | awk  '{print $2}')
   sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ddebs.list << EOF
deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/ ${codename}      main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/ ${codename}-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/ ${codename}-updates  main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/ ${codename}-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
EOF

   sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys ECDCAD72428D7C01
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r)-dbgsym
```

After this, the program worked ok.